# Q. speed between "R with indicator" and "c++ with for"

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I felt the speed of the following R code is good. Is there any way to increase speed using c++? I felt my c++ code is not that faster.

```
#R-code
> s<-5
> t<-2
> y<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
> r<-c(1,5,5,3,3)
> 
> sindex<-r[r==s]
> tindex<-r[r==t]
> 
> 
> res<-sum(y[sindex])+sum(y[tindex])
> 
> sindex
[1] 5 5
> tindex
numeric(0)
> 
> res
[1] 10

#c++
res1=0; res2=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
if(r[i]==s){
    res1=res1+y[s];
}
if(r[i]==t){
    res2=res2+y[t];
}
}
res=res1+res2
```

Comment: With your trivial example, any speed ups will be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorization in R (sum is a vectorized function) runs in C in the background. Often speedy enough...

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
res = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     if (r[i] == s || r[i] == t)
          res += y[i];   // y[s] or y[t] seems incorrect
```

Do not expect it to be much more faster.